# How do I deter a visiting doggie from a sewerage leak in my garden?

Tags: dogs

My friend is coming to visit in a couple of days with her young Labrador. I don't have my own dog.

In the past week, we had a relatively minor sewerage leak in the bottom of the garden. It's been fixed and treated with lyme and bleach as appropriate. There is still a light smell which is expected to go away.

I am concerned that 
1) The visiting doggie is going to be drawn to this end of the garden due to the smell, and
2) The chemicals used in treating the leak could be harmful to the dog.

There is plenty of other garden, (it's only one corner, a few sqm out of a thousand or so), and I expect my friend to be around to keep an eye on her doggie. Nonetheless, I'm still concerned for his safety.

Apart from physically cordoning-off the part in question, which I would consider if absolutely necessary, is there any other measure I can take, like something I could spray to deter his doggie nose?